# How to plot hatch-breed created by two different breeds

Tags: netlogo

I am having some troubles to plot objects created using hatch.
I would like to plot objects created by engineersA and engineersB, separately.
After JenB’s answer, the code that I am using for this purpose is

```
sk one-of turtles with [breed = engineersA or breed = engineersB]

    [ if empty? my-list
      [ set size random-float 1
      ]


        hatch-objects random 10
          [ hide-turtle
            ask myself
            [ set my-list fput self my-list
            ]
          ]
        ]
```

What I tried to do is

```
ask engineersA [plotxy ticks objects]
```

same for engineersB.

Unfortunately, because of objects as a breed, it does not work.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: What are you trying to plot about objects? Do you want the number of them (`count`), or the mean value of some variable or something else? Also, now that you have a little experience with NetLogo, I strongly recommend that you redo the tutorials, have a look at some of the models in the library, and maybe have a look at the resources page for other materials. There are some examples with plots.

Comment: Yes, I am looking at the resources page and at the material on the web, but I have not found any example with the hatch. I would like to count the breeds' objects/size, but this question is more general as I have not found any useful example on the net (with plots there are a lot, but with hatch just a few and not specifically related to what I am trying to do)

Comment: Wade is correct, the code would not have added to the list. See that answer for the corrected code. As I asked there, you need to check that the code works before moving on to something else. It is hard to create minimum working examples in NetLogo and it's hard to debug, so you need to check things before writing even more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are problems with context in your hatch-objects code,  particularly with what values "self" and "myself" take on. The code as written will never put any objects on the my-lists.  Explaining it is difficult so I wrote code (that runs) with a verbose? variable in setup. If you set verbose? to true, the print commands will print out what's going on in each step of the code. ( if you set it to false, the print commands won't print anything.)

At the end of the code are the commands I used to get a plot of the counts of objects created by each breed of Engineers.  That is documented in the code right there, and it works correctly.

I decided to store text values of "A" or "B" in each object to show what breed created that object.   It was a problem to store the breed in that variable and test for it, so I just used text, which worked.

I made the turtles large so that they were easy to click on an inspect.

This should be enough of an example for you to figure out how to compute and store the other things you want to do.

```
globals [
verbose?  ;; set this true to print out debugging info
count-type-a  ;; count of objects created by engineersA
count-type-b  ;; count of objects created by engineersB
]

breed [engineersA engineerA]
engineersA-own [ my-list]

breed [engineersB engineerB]
engineersB-own [my-list]

breed [objects object]
objects-own[
creator-breed  ;; set to either "A" or "B"
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set verbose? true   ;; turns on and off debugging print statements

  create-engineersA 3 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label who set size 3
    set my-list []
    ]

 create-engineersB 3 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label who set size 3
    set my-list []
    ]


  reset-ticks
end

to go
  let breed-picked "none"

  ask one-of turtles with [breed = engineersA or breed = engineersB]

    [
    ;;set breed-picked breed   ( produces a result that looks like a string but isn't)

    if-else ( breed = engineersA) [
      if verbose? [ print " this is breed engineersa "]
      set breed-picked "A" ]
    [ set breed-picked "B" ]

    if verbose? [ print ( word  "we are looking at turtle " who  " now, which is breed " breed-picked) ]

    if   my-list = []
      [
        if verbose? [print "my-list is empty"]
        ; set size random-float 1
      ]


        hatch-objects 3
          [
            set size 3 set color yellow set shape "circle"
            set creator-breed breed-picked
            if verbose? [
             print ( word " in hatch-objects, myself = " myself)
             print ( word " in hatch-objects, self = " self)
            ]

            let object-tag self ;; so this will persist into ask myself
            hide-turtle
            ask myself
            [     
                 if verbose? [
                  print ( word " in ask myself, self = " self )
                  print ( word " in ask myself, object-tag = " object-tag)
                  print ( word " who of object-tag " [who] of object-tag )
                 ]

                  set my-list fput object-tag my-list
        if verbose? [ print ( word   "hatched an object,  my-list is now " my-list)]
            ]


          ]
     ]
  if verbose? [ ask objects [ print creator-breed]]

   set count-type-a count objects with[ creator-breed = "A" ]
   set count-type-b count objects with[ creator-breed = "B" ]
   print ( word "count of objects created by engineersA is now " count-type-a)
   print ( word "count of objects created by engineersB is now " count-type-b)

   ;;  The following code works. I'm sure there are better ways to do it.
   ;;  The interface has a plot called "plot 1"
   ;;  Within that plot object, two pens were created, called "type-a" and "type-b"
   ;;      and the pens were given different colors.
   ;;  The check box for "show legend" was checked.
   ;;  Everything else was left at default values. The plot commands were left blank.

   set-current-plot "plot 1"   
   set-current-plot-pen "type-a"
   plot count-type-a

   set-current-plot-pen "type-b"
   plot count-type-b

end
```